# Top users page for a tag should indicate that one's self is not necessarily part of the list

Tags: feature-request, design, top-users

For quite some time, I’ve thought that I was a top asker in [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) based on the [top users tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/topusers), which always bewildered me because I’ve asked very few questions (none of which have extraordinarily high scores). In fact, that gap between me and the “next” person up the list is 160 rep.!

But now I’ve realized that it’s just showing me for comparative purposes, not because I’m actually on the list. This, however, is not obvious at all just looking at the list:

[image: Screenshot showing the list]

There’s nothing to indicate that there’s a break/cut in the list. One might discover it based on the large difference in numbers, but if the numbers are reasonably close this may not be the case.

Ultimately, it’s rather misleading. The list should either be numbered, with the current user having their correct number rather than just the next one (like it is in [the leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow)), or some sort of border to indicate the list breaks. Or something else entirely that would set the comparative, non-top entry apart from the others.

Comment: The user search feature in the leagues does a better job of this.

Comment: @Ernest I am aware that there exist weekly/monthly/quarterly reputation leagues. Are there also leagues by tag?

Comment: norepro, you're not on that page! but weirdly *I* am... ;)

Comment: @Asad Oops, that’s not what I’d meant by that sentence. I’ve edited to remove the ambiguity (I meant that none of the questions I’ve asked had very high scores, rather than implying the questions I did ask often had high scores).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I figured after the edit, no worries. :)